# Cordova plugin for running app in background in Android 9

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

[cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues) doesn't seem to be working anymore on `Android 9`. Is there a similar, working plugin for keeping my `app active in the background`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cordova-plugin-background-mode-fixed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode-fixed) works for me